# Add border to all images

Tags: latex

I have a document that has a handful of figures in it, and I am using

```
\tcbox{\includegraphics{./Pictures/image-name.png}}
```

to put a border around them. I end up repeating this for every image though. Is there a way to put something at the top of my document that says to apply this to all images?

Comment: Does any of images has optional arguments, e.g. `\includegraphics[width=3cm]{...}`?

Comment: They all have the same width argument (10cm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing else in your document relies on `\includegraphics`, you could try the following redefinition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\let\includegraphicsold\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\tcbox{\includegraphicsold[#1]{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-duck}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You are amazing!!! Is this taking `includegraphics` and making that `includegraphicsold` then redefining `includegraphics` to take two arguments with the arguments being put into `includegraphicsold`? I didn't really know this was possible, thank you!

Comment: @Hercislife You're welcome! Basically yes.